# обновление здоровья

Tags: python, pygame

Всем привет, делаю игру по типу космического шутера. Есть код и картинки, всё приложу. Помогите, как можно сделать что бы при наборе 1000 очков, здоровье игрока обновлялось до 100?

```
import random
from os import path

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font_name = pygame.font.match_font('arial')


def draw_text(surf, text, size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_name, size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)


def newmob():
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)


def draw_shield_bar(surf, x, y, pct):
    if pct < 0:
        pct = 0
    BAR_LENGTH = 100
    BAR_HEIGHT = 10
    fill = (pct / 100) * BAR_LENGTH
    fill_rect = pygame.Rect((WIDTH / 2) - 45, 65, fill, BAR_HEIGHT)
    outline_rect = pygame.Rect((WIDTH / 2) - 45, 65, BAR_LENGTH, BAR_HEIGHT)
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, WHITE, outline_rect, 3)
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, GREEN, fill_rect)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 38))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = 20
        # pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.shield = 100
        self.shoot_delay = 250
        self.last_shot = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 5
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = - 5
        self.rect.y += self.speedy

        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT
        self.speedx = 0

        if keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.shoot()

    def shoot(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if now - self.last_shot > self.shoot_delay:
            self.last_shot = now
            bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
            all_sprites.add(bullet)
            bullets.add(bullet)


class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image_orig = random.choice(meteor_images)
        self.image_orig.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image = self.image_orig.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = int(self.rect.width * .85 / 2)
        # pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-150, -100)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.rot = 0
        self.rot_speed = random.randrange(-8, 8)
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def rotate(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > 50:
            self.last_update = now
            self.rot = (self.rot + self.rot_speed) % 360
            new_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image_orig, self.rot)
            old_center = self.rect.center
            self.image = new_image
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = old_center

    def update(self):
        self.rotate()
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > WIDTH + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = bullet_img
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()


background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "startfield.jpg")).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()
player_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "playerShip2_red.png")).convert()
bullet_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "laserRed13.png")).convert()
meteor_images = []
meteor_list = ['meteorGrey_med2.png', 'meteorBrown_big4.png', 'meteorBrown_big2.png',
               'meteorGrey_med2.png']
for img in meteor_list:
    meteor_images.append(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, img)).convert())

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
for i in range(8):
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)
score = 0

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

    all_sprites.update()

    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
    for hit in hits:
        score += 50 - hit.radius
        newmob()

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, True, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
    for hit in hits:
        player.shield -= hit.radius * 2
        newmob()
        if player.shield <= 0:
            running = False

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(background, background_rect)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    draw_text(screen, str(score), 40, WIDTH / 2, 10)
    draw_shield_bar(screen, 5, 5, player.shield)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Вот ссылка на яндекс.диск, со всеми нужными изображениями: https://disk.yandex.ru/client/disk

Comment: if score >=1000: player.shield=100

Comment: Добавь решение Интика в главный цикл (while running)

Comment: помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на

```
if переменная_с_количенством_очков >= 100:
   переменная_со_здоровьем = 1000
```